# vim : delete from cursor to _

Tags: vim, normal-mode

in some case I have name of variables with a `_` like `hello_world`.

in vim, in normal mode, with `dw`, I can delete from cursor position to end of word.

How I can delete from current cursor position to `-` ?

In the `hello_world` case, I can make this with `df_`, but, exist a general way ? (and without delete the `_`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To delete from the cursor up to but not including the `_`, type

```
dt_
```

I don't know what you mean by a "general way". You can find more here:

```
:help d
:help motion.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

My [camelcasemotion plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1905) provides movements and text objects especially for `CamelCaseWords` and `underscore_notation`. With it, you can delete `hello` in your example via `d,e`.